# MPMoviePlayer No Longer Seeks Forward and instead gives warning

Tags: iphone, uikit, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotification

So it appears as though my MPMoviePlayer no longer wants to seek forward, despite it being the case that seeking is done internally by the MoviePlayer, so all I should be doing is setting up notifications in order to know that seeking is occurring.

So I setup my notification as such:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self          
   selector:@selector(playbackStateDidChange:)            
   name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:theMovie];
```

Then, inside playbackStateDidChange: I have the following relevant code:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mpc = [notification object];
MPMoviePlaybackState state = mpc.playbackState;
if (state==MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward)
    NSLog(@"playback state is seeking forward");
```

Finally, when I hold down the forward seek button, playbackStateDidChange indeed gets invoked, and indeed says "playback state is seeking forward," but I see no discernible change in the behavior of the movie.  However, the 2nd time I try to seek forward I receive this warning in my console:

WARNING: _inflightSeekRate already set, which means multiple setRate:error: calls have been made before a _rateDidChangeNotification was received

So basically, the forward seek isn't working properly, and I have a hunch that this is an MPMoviePlayer bug, but I couldn't find anything online to back my claim, nor answer my question.  If anybody has any good ideas about how to handle this issue (maybe a workaround) I'm all ears.

Thanks;

-Steve

P.S. - I should mention that my MPMoviePlayer seeking worked just fine until I upgraded my X-Code/iPhone SDK last week.  Now it appears to be just fine, except for the forward seeking.